# Обработка русского текста

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. У меня стоит английская винда и студия. Мне понадобилось обработать русский текст, но при вводе строки, в дебаггере вижу, что строка состоит из одних символов '?'. Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно сделать? Использую

```
std::string
```

Comment: Используйте [`std::wstring`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_wstring/) и, в том случае, если ввод осуществляется из консоли, [правильную локаль и `std::wcin` для ввода.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230319/how-to-read-a-users-input-from-the-console-into-a-unicode-string)

Comment: Делаю так:

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    wstring s;
    wcin>>s

Вводит и выводит правильно, но, когда работаю со строкой, вместо русских букв иероглифы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простое решение. Кодировка консоли и локаль устанавливаются на русскую кодировку CP_1251. В этом случае чтение/запись в консоль где-то "внутри" оборачивается преобразованием из Юникода/в Юникод.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP( 1251 ); // настраиваем кодировку консоли (ввод)
    SetConsoleOutputCP( 1251 ); // (вывод)

    // настраиваем внутренние механизмы на эту кодировку
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1251");

    std::wstring line;
    std::getline( std::wcin, line );
    std::wcout << L"Привет, " << line << std::endl;
}
```

У меня получилось добиться того, чтобы сама консоль работала в режиме "Юникод" на вывод, но тот же фокус на ввод не прошёл:

```
int main()
{
    _setmode( fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT );
    std::wstring line( L"Привет2" );
    std::wcout << line << std::endl;
}
```